# Unable to find Area View in ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-areas

A new project is unable to find the views for a new Area.

It is trying to find it in the parent Views folder.

A suggested solution is to put `.DataTokens.Add("area", "AREANAME")` into the `RegisterArea` method.

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
        {
            context.MapRoute(
                "Test_default",
                "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
            ).DataTokens.Add("area", "Test");
        }
```

However, with this, I'm getting an "*An item with the same key has already been added.*" error.

UPDATE 1: I'm not doing anything fancy on the controller.

```
public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
```

UPDATE 2: I just would like to add that I'm also registering components into a Unity container. I don't think this is causing issues, though, because it explicitly states that it is not necessary to register my controllers.

Comment: Show us your controller action.

Comment: I have updated above to show that there's nothing special in my controller.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's most likely because the View is being searched from namespace

```
YourNamespace.YourApplication.Controllers
```

and instead it should be looked from namespace (or what ever namespace you have defined)

```
YourNamespace.YourApplication.Areas.Test.Controllers
```

Add following to your route declaration

```
public override void RegisterArea(AreaRegistrationContext context) 
{
    context.MapRoute(
        "Test_default",
        "Test/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        new { action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
        namespaces: new[] { "YourNamespace.YourApplication.Areas.Test.Controllers" }
    );
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The method `Register Area` already know you are in your Area named `Test`. Using the function `DataTokens.Add("area", "Test")` declares a second time your route. That's why you get this error.

The initial issue for your view is certainly not related to your routing settings. Is there a custom code when rendering the view from the controller ?

Answer (score 1):

I've found that if your route declaration isn't above the "catch all" route declaration (usually your parent views as you pointed out), it will default to the parent each time. Try moving the route declaration above anything the parent will try to catch

Comment: Route declaration for the areas are called from AreaRegistration, which is called before RouteConfig in my global.asax.cs.